# Removing duplicate rows from a CSV file

Tags: ruby

I want to remove CSV rows that have the same value in two columns. `uniq` can be passed as a block, but I cannot figure it out:

```
CSV.open( "csv/competition-duped.csv", 'w' ) do | csv |
  CSV.read( file ).uniq{ | column | column.values_at( column[ 3 ], column[ 7 ] ) }.each do | row |
    csv << row
  end
end
```

Further to this, I may have found the solution.

```
CSV.read( file ).uniq{ | column | [ column[ 3 ], column[ 7 ] ] }.each do | row |
```

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Can you add an extract of your csv file with some duplicated rows?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it managing two files, the main file which has the data, and the output file where you'll write just the wanted data.

```
require 'csv'

main = CSV.read('csv/competition-duped.csv')
unwanted = nil

# Open the out file in write file mode
CSV.open('csv/out.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  # Add the headers of the main csv file
  csv << main.shift
  # Iterate for every row in your original csv file
  main.each do |data|
    # Check for duplicated data
    if data[0] != unwanted
      unwanted = data[0]
      # If isn't then write in the out file the data
      csv << data
    end
  end
end
```

I tried to do it in a shorter way and I get this:

```
# Open the out file in write file mode
CSV.open('csv/out.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  CSV.read('csv/competition-duped.csv').uniq.each { |r| csv << r }
end
```